# Get RadioButton of List by Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a table with data and radiobuttons, which can be checked: accept, pending, refuse.
On Save I want to check if any radiobutton is still in the state of pending.
How can I do that?

The Radio Buttons look like this:

```
<td class="fit">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="pad0"><div class=""><fmt:message key='status.registration.registered'/>:</div></td>
   <c:if test="${participation.registrationStatus == 2}"><td class="pad0 padL10"><spring:radiobutton path="assignmentFormArray[${i}].registrationStatus" value="2" checked="checked"/></td></c:if>
   <c:if test="${participation.registrationStatus != 2}"><td class="pad0 padL10"><spring:radiobutton path="assignmentFormArray[${i}].registrationStatus" value="2"/></td></c:if>
  </tr><tr>
   <td class="pad0"><div class=""><fmt:message key='status.registration.pending'/>:</div></td>
   <c:if test="${participation.registrationStatus == 1}"><td class="pad0 padL10"><spring:radiobutton path="assignmentFormArray[${i}].registrationStatus" value="1" checked="checked"/></td></c:if>
   <c:if test="${participation.registrationStatus != 1}"><td class="pad0 padL10"><spring:radiobutton path="assignmentFormArray[${i}].registrationStatus" value="1"/></td></c:if>
  </tr><tr>
   <td class="pad0"><div class=""><fmt:message key='status.registration.declined'/>:</div></td>
   <c:if test="${participation.registrationStatus == 6}"><td class="pad0 padL10"><spring:radiobutton path="assignmentFormArray[${i}].registrationStatus" value="6" checked="checked"/></td></c:if>
   <c:if test="${participation.registrationStatus != 6}"><td class="pad0 padL10"<spring:radiobutton path="assignmentFormArray[${i}].registrationStatus" value="6"/></td> </c:if>
  </tr>
 </table>
</td>
```

I tried the following Javascript Function:

```
function save(){
 alert($("input:radio[value='1']:checked"));
}
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. It always alerts with an object, even when no radiobutton with value 1 is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. But thanks to anyone who wanted to help:

```
function save() {
 var isPending = false;
 $("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 1){
        isPending = true;
    };
 });
 if (isPending){
    alert("isPending");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('input:radio[name=name of radio button]:checked').val();
```

This will give you the value of selected radio button.. you can check that whether that is pending or accept or reject...

Comment: But I have maybe 50 Radiobuttons, and I need to know of one of them has the value 1 (=pending)...
With your code I can find out, if one radiobutton of a group has the value 1 (=pending).

Answer (score 0):

i think u can create a simple boolean array
which stores the values of the radio buttons
on change of radio buttons u need to call a set method every time
this is just  like a bean to set and get the values of the form element , on save 
u can simply check the boolean array